# NetCDF Values from a reader (Panoply/NC.view) vs Python (rioxarray)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, netcdf, cdo-climate

For some reason, values at each time step for a NC file I'm using appear different when I view it through an external reader like Panoply and when I process it through a Python script via rioxarray.open_rasterio.

Scaling Factor is 1.0 and Offset is 0 so it shouldn't be causing a discrepancy. Has anyone encountered this issue previously?

Dataset is "pr_aus_CESM1-CAM5_rcp45_r1i1p1_CSIRO-DecCh-wrt-1986-2005-Scl_v1_day_2016-2045.nc" downloaded from here: [text](https://data-cbr.csiro.au/thredds/catalog/catch_all/oa-aus5km/Climate_Change_in_Australia_User_Data/Application_Ready_Data_Gridded_Daily/Rainfall_(Precipitation)/2016-2045/catalog.html)

I've first opened it via Panoply and looked the rainfall value at Timestep 0 at (141.95, -20.65) which reads at 0.1097mm.

I've then used the below code to read it into Python and at the same Time/Coordinates the value for "b" is 0

`pr=rioxarray.open_rasterio("pr_aus_CESM1-CAM5_rcp45_r1i1p1_CSIRO-DecCh-wrt-1986-2005-Scl_v1_day_2016-2045.nc")`

`a = pr[0,:,:]*pr.attrs['scale_factor']+pr.attrs['add_offset']`

`b = a.values`

Comment: The dataset is hosted in my org so is relatively easy to access. I used `pr[0,:,:].sel(x=141.95, y=-20.65).values` and obtained `array(0.10973778, dtype=float32)`.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Did you use rioxarry to read in the data as well?

Comment: Yes I did. Please supply the exact code you used to access the x=141.95, y=-20.65 point which returned a zero. I think you will find that it is a case of user error.